# React render infinite loop when reading file content before upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, filereader, redux-form

I'm trying to display some file contents in a React/Redux app when the file has been selected for upload using the FileReader API. I am able to display the contents but calling setState inside the FileReader's onload event handler is causing an infinite render to occur.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Select,
  TextField,
} from 'redux-form-material-ui';

import { renderFileInput } from '../helpers/form_helpers';

class ImportLeads extends Component {
  state = {
    fields: []
  }

  handleFormSubmit({ leadsCSV }) {
    const { listid } = this.props;
    this.props.importLeads(leadsCSV, listid);
  }

  renderMapping() {
    const { CSVFile } = this.props;
    console.log(CSVFile);
    const temp = [];

    if(CSVFile) {
      const r = new FileReader();
      r.readAsText(CSVFile, "UTF-8");
      r.onload = (e) => {
        const content = e.target.result;
        const firstLine = content.split('\n', 1)[0];
        const fieldsArray = firstLine.split(',');
        console.log(fieldsArray);
        _.map(fieldsArray, field => {
          console.log(field);
          temp.push(<div>{field}</div>);
        });
        this.setState({ fields: temp });
      }
      r.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error reading file");
      }
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.fields}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <div>

            <Field
              name="leadsCSV"
              component={renderFileInput}
              type="file"
              text="Import CSV"
            />

            <div style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
              <Button type="submit" variant="raised">Upload</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        {this.renderMapping()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ImportLeads = reduxForm({
  form: 'importLeads',
})(ImportLeads);

const selector = formValueSelector('importLeads');
ImportLeads = connect(
  state => {
    const CSVFile = selector(state, 'leadsCSV');
    return {
      CSVFile
    }
  }
)(ImportLeads);

export default ImportLeads;
```

I use redux form to handle the file input and get the value of the file by making it available as props using connect.

I read that an infinite render usually occurs when setState is called inside the render method. Is there a better way to approach this and not have it rendering infinitely? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React has special "lifecycle" methods that are useful for exactly this use case.

If you define a `componentWillMount()` method, it will get called before the first render. If you have additional resources you need to load you could kick that off there.

Since it looks like you want to re-run those calculations if the props change you will also want to use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to re-run your calculations based on the new props. Note that `this.props` does not yet reflect the new props, you'll need to get those from the arguments.

Finally, while unnecessary for your case you should familizarize yourself with `componentWillUnmount()` which will allow you to clean up after yourself (e.g. remove event listeners, cancel timers, etc.) if you fail to do that you can easily cause memory leaks and worse.

There quite a few more lifecycle methods you could familiarize yourself with in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Finally a sample to demonstrate how you might go about using those methods to solve a similar problem of "parsing" a newline separated list.

```js
class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        rows: []
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.parse(this.props.string);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.parse(nextProps.string);
      
    }

    parse(string) {
      // Dummy placeholder for asynchronous operation
      this.setState({
        rows: string.split("\n")
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ul>
          { this.state.rows.map((row) => <li>{row}</li>) }
        </ul>
      );
    }
}

class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { string: "hello world\ngoodbye world" };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <Table string={this.state.string} />
      <textarea onChange={(event) => this.setState({ string: event.target.value })} value={this.state.string} />
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Sample /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In my case componentWillReceiveProps was the only thing required since the prop was available only after the file gets added to be uploaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `renderMapping()`,you calling `setState` causing to re-render the component.

In component `render`, you have `{this.renderMapping()}` causing to call again `renderMapping`.

This process getting repeated n time causing infinite rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You should check in your `renderMapping` if the `fieldsArray` is already contains `field`. If so, you should not push it to the array. (Because you are pushing the same field in another div into your array its constantly causing re-render)

```
if (fieldsArray.includes(field)) {
  return;
}
```